# iPhone4: Application loses all data saved in CoreData on click home button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

Am having a serious problem: my app runs perfectly on iphone 3GS, but having problems with iPhone4: when the user taps home button then reopen the app, all the data saved in database are vanished. I cant't explain what is happening, the app used to run fine on both devices (with different os), then when i did some changes on the entities of coreData, this problem occures: I tried to delete the XcDataModel and recreate it, the problem is the same. Any help please?

ps:  I tested the app on a new iPhone 4 device (i didn't run on it any previous version of the app ) and I have the same problem

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: sorry i don't have an iPhone 4 to test directly the app and see the logs, am triynig to get one very soon in order to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure to [-save:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/save%3a) your `NSManagedObjectContext` when your application is going to resign its active state? This could be in [-[UIApplicationDelegate applicationWillResignActive:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW9) or in response to a [UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW59).

Comment: But it works fine on iPhone 3GS, so thats not the problem, is it?

Comment: If you're only saving your data on quit, maybe the 3GS is actually terminating your application, while the iPhone 4 is perhaps only moving it to the background. Either way, you should always save when you resign active, and you can't depend on any behaviors you get without doing that.

Comment: No my app is ranning on background on 3GS, am sure of that

Comment: I realized that at that stage applicationWillREsignActive, it is too late for Core data to be saved. My Coredata doesnt save in that method, while it saves if I put the code to work for an action method of a button